# AngularJS filter unable to filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to explore the `AngularJS` filter but the code which I am trying is not working.

JSFiddle for the same is: http://jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/5bp5v1z0/1/

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Name"/></td>
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items ">
    <tr ng-repeat="temp in item | filter:search">                        
        <td>{{temp[0].Name}}</td>
        <td>{{temp[0].Price}}</td>
        <td>{{temp[0].Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your items object is not constructed very well and I think it should be smth like this

```
$scope.items = [
            {
                Name: "Account Opening R75",
                Price: "R75",
                Quantity: "A_O-AngularJS"      
            }
            ,
            {
                Name: "AVClientService",
                Price: "R74",
                Quantity: "AVClientService-DotNet"     
            }
        ];
```

Also, I modified your code snnipet like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">                        
                        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Price}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

For the complete example check this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5bp5v1z0/3/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but i tried this already and it works, my JSON is in that way, i had to group the application name and now apply angularjs filter,how to solve my scenario, modifying JSON is only way?

Comment: I am trying to create a custom filter to do this thing as i cant ask my Service team to change JSON structure.